# How can I generate a configmap from a directory of files that need to be templated?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can generate the `ConfigMap` from the directory but they are not translating the template directives or values. Below is an example of the `Release.Namespace` template directive not being output in the `ConfigMap`.

```
.
|____Chart.yaml
|____charts
|____.helmignore
|____templates
| |____my-scripts.yaml
|____values.yaml
|____test-files
  |____test1.txt
```

```
---
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  test.txt: |-
{{ .Files.Get "test-files/test1.txt" | indent 4}}
```

```
# test-files/test1.txt
test file
{{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

When I run `helm install . --dry-run --debug --namespace this-should-print` here's what I'm getting vs what I'm expecting:

Actual:

```
---
# Source: test/templates/my-scripts.yaml
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: test
data:
  test.txt: |-
    # test-files/test1.txt
    test file
    {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

Expected:

```
---
# Source: test/templates/my-scripts.yaml
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: test
data:
  test.txt: |-
    # test-files/test1.txt
    test file
    this-should-print
```

Alternatively, I would be interested in every file in a specified directory being output in the format like:

```
<filename>: |-
  <content>
```

Comment: Great example of a well-asked SO question: all the necessary info about your input (directory structure, content of key files), what command you ran, exactly what you got and exactly what you expected. Very nice!

Comment: quick tip, you can run `helm template` instead of `helm install --dry-run`

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way of doing it using the tpl function:

```
---
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  test.txt: |-
{{ tpl ( .Files.Get "test-files/test1.txt" ) . | indent 4 }}
```

The new output is exactly as expected:

```
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: this-should-print
data:
  test.txt: |-
    # test-files/test1.txt
    test file
    this-should-print
```

And for bonus points, getting all files from a directory without having to update this list within the config map:

```
---
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
{{ tpl (.Files.Glob "groovy-scripts/*").AsConfig . | indent 4 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Files.Get` will take the raw contents of those files and dump it into your resulting YAMLs, if you want those file contents to be subject to Helm template rendering themselves, this approach won't work. You can instead create [named templates](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_template_guide/named_templates/) and then `include` them within other templates.

Directory Structure: `tree`

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── _test1.tpl
│   └── my-scripts.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Template: `cat templates/my-scripts.yaml`

```
---
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  test.txt: |-
{{- include "mychart.test1" . | indent 4 }}
```

Helper: `cat templates/_test1.tpl`

```
{{- define "mychart.test1" }}
test file
{{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- end }}
```

Result: `helm template . --namespace this-should-print`

```
---
# Source: helm/templates/my-scripts.yaml
---
# templates/myscripts.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-scripts
  namespace: this-should-print
data:
  test.txt: |-
    test file
    this-should-print
```